# How to return multiple objects and only show part of the return when we call the function

Tags: r

For user defined function, I use list if there are multiple objects to return.

However, not all information are equal important. 
For example, I am writing a function which estimates for 3 parameters by iteration. The final converged result is the most important, so I would like to see 3 numbers after I call my function. While the history of iteration (all steps of estimation) sometimes is needed, but printing out all steps all the time occupies the whole screen.

Currently, I use list to return 3 matrices, which contains all steps.
Is there a way that make the function return the same thing, but when I call the function, it only show the last 3 converged estimates. And if I need the estimation step, then I use $ to get them. So it looks like:

```
MyEstimate(arg1, arg2, ...)      # only show 3 final estimates

model <- MyEstimate(arg1, arg2, ...)
model$theta1                     # show all steps of estimates of theta1
```

Basically, I want it works like 'lm' function: 
    Show something important, like estimates of parameters;
    Don't show, but still can access if we want, like the design matrix X

---

I reckon there is no simple answer for that. 
To achieved this, what should I learn?

Comment: You can use `print` in the function for what you want to show e.g 3 estimators, whenever you call the function. And the detailed information are in the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print` to always print the values you are interested in when you call the function, while maintain all information in the returned object.

```
> myFun <- function(){
   a <- sample(1:10, 10, TRUE)
   b <- sample(1:10, 10, TRUE)
   c <- sample(1:10, 10, TRUE)

   # Print Last value
   print(tail(a,1))
   print(tail(b,1))
   print(tail(c,1))
   return(list(a = a, b=b, c=c))
 }

> Obj <- myFun()
[1] 10
[1] 5
[1] 2

> Obj
$a
 [1]  2  9  4  7  3  2  2  5  1 10

$b
 [1] 6 4 9 8 8 9 2 8 6 5

$c
 [1] 2 6 9 2 6 7 8 2 6 2
```

Comment: this method achieved what I want, but also did more than that, since it always print the 'important' thing even I don't want it. For example, Obj <- myFun() will also print. But I guess it is the easiest way

Comment: If you don't mind, you can pass a flag parameters when you assign, such that if you want to print or not

Comment: Could you plz be more explicit? How do I set the flag parameter inside a function that the function would be assign?

Comment: `myFun <- function( ....., print.flag = 1) { ... if(print.flag){ print(tail(...) } }` and when you call the function you can decide if you want to print or not by the flag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the S3 classes mechanism to have your function `MyEstimate` return an object of a special class, made up by you, and write a `print` method for that class. You would *subclass* class `"list"`.

If this special class is named `"tautology"` you would write method `print.tautology`. Something along the lines of the following:

```
print.tautology <- function(x){
  h <- tail(x[[1]], 3)
  print(h)
  invisible(h)
}


MyEstimate <- function(x, y, ...){
  res <- list(theta1 = 1:10, beta2 = 11:15)
  class(res) <- c("tautology", class(res))
  res
}

arg1 <- 1
arg2 <- 2
MyEstimate(arg1, arg2)      # only show 3 final estimates
#[1]  8  9 10

model <- MyEstimate(arg1, arg2)
model$theta1                   # show all steps of estimates of theta1
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Is `print.tautology` a method that would "suppress" the outcome  (show in console) of **any object** with class "tautology" in it? And it will perform this "suppress" once we have this method in workspace, we don't need to call it? I checked with some toy examples, the answer is yes, but still not sure as I never use method in R before.

Comment: @tautology Yes, you are right. `print.tautology` would be called on an object of class `tautology`, be it when you call `print(model)`, be it with autoprinting, running just `model`.